# How do I unlock the Tower Defense AR challenge?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

In order to continue the game, I have to complete the Tower Defense AR challenge, but it is locked until I pick up a downed enemy into a beat down move. How do I do that? Is there a place in the game I can learn this move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an enemy Is on the floor you need to pick them back up using right trigger + B (Xbox One), R2 + O (PS4) and then just keep punching them until they are KO'd.

Comment: In case you wanted to add it to your answer the place you learn this move is on leaving the airships the first time.

Comment: @Chris I don't think so. I couldn't get to the airships until I completed this challenge.

Comment: Hmmm... I was pretty sure that it was the fight as you left the second airship where I first got a prompt that said "trigger + B to pick somebody up and keep hitting them". Then again I don't recall having to complete any challenges to progress either. Are you sure you didn't just confuse a waypoint location? I think that that challenge is in the same place as you pick up the remote hacking device (roof of wayne tower). Did it definitely tell you to complete the challenge? (I just looked up some walkthroughs and they didn't mention it but that doesn't mean anything).